# Common test result attributes

Tags: terminology

I am having troubles finding the right words or labels for a part inspection as my native language is not English and I can't seem to find the right search keywords to look at application descriptions.
In the medical sense, a test is positive if the assertion (a condition/sickness) results true, e.g. "yes, I'm sick", the illness tested for is present. But what about "binary binning" of objects/parts?

- Good/Bad
- OK/Not OK
- positive/negative
- true/false
- ??/defective
- ??/error

... ?

Comment: The word _error_ does not really fit with the rest of these, because _error_ is a noun, whereas the rest of them are adjectives. It's hard to find the "opposite" of a noun. As for _defective_, you can simply say _not defective_, or, perhaps more elegantly, _free from defects_.

Comment: Of course, that was thoughless of me. Here's a more conclusive listing: http://thesaurus.com/browse/defective
But I'm rather looking for the common technical term that may even be abbreviated, e.g. maybe "NOK"

Comment: My first suggestion would be: Defective/Defect-free. But if you want abbreviations, OK/NOK would work just fine. It wouldn't take a lot of training to explain what those two abbreviations meant.

Comment: Different fields, and even different standards within a given field, will have different terminology. We tell you that the most common technical term is "pass", you go ahead and use it in a context where the expected term is "no error", and bam you're in trouble. What *is* your application field? Read your standards, look at what your peers do, ask your supervisors. And if you have none of these things, then you're not after a specific term after all, and whether you use "pass", "adequate", "no error", "working", or "perfect" is completely up to you, so the question has no single answer.

Comment: While you're absolutely right that it depends on the context, "pass/fail" might be a valuable mention and an element of the solution set. The field is production of parts. I'm trying to improve on what supervisor/peers came up with.. :-) But I'm also happy to hear that OK/NOK seem to be recognized abbreviations / labels, so I might just go with that. Thanks to both of you so far (but I'm still listening).

Comment: Can use Perfect for Defective.

Comment: Positive/Negative are typically used in medical tests and are represented in notes and reports as + or -

Answer (score 2):

Pass/fail would be common terms for the result of a binary test to see if something is working correctly.

You might also consider accept/reject for parts that are being tested to see if they comply with a specification.